# CSS vertical height justification

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

Please help with auto vertical height for `div` or `li` elements via CSS.
When I do this with table:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" height="600">IMG width=100% height=auto</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MG2Dh/), every cell in the right column has 1/5 of the left cell's height. How can I do this without table and only with `div` or `li` elements?
The left cell's height is not known; the element is responsive.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MG2Dh/1/) ?

Comment: Not quite see it http://jsfiddle.net/MG2Dh/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="width:50%;height:100px;float:left;line-height:227px">test</div>
    <div style="width:49%;float:right;border:1px solid red;">
        <div style="height:50px;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:46px">1</div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:46px">1</div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:46px">1</div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:46px">1</div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:100%;border:1px solid #ddd;line-height:46px">1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In your code the height of left div has fix-height 250px. I don't know  in advance the height of the element. See http://jsfiddle.net/MG2Dh/2/ the right div.preview have no full height.

Answer (score 0):

*HTML*

```
<div class="parent">IMG width=100% height=auto</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
div{   
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.parent {
    height:600px;
    float:left;
}
.parent div {
    height:19.7%;//must be 20%, but 19.7 is to accommodate 1px border 
}
```

***[`Working Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kF2b5/)***

Comment: The height left div is not known, the element is responsive. If I knew the height of the element, then yes, this code is correct.

Comment: @Um-ko Merge my answer with some tricks *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270624/2260614)* or *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2997838/2260614)* and finally *[faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)*... And using *[`display:table and using display:table-cell I reached here`](http://jsfiddle.net/kF2b5/1/)*